# How to set env in package.json which is used within .bablerc

Tags: javascript, webpack, jestjs, babeljs

I am trying to run Jest tests as part of a script before I then run webpack, like this.

```
npm run test
webpack --progress --profile --watch --mode development
```

Jest only works with compiled code, so I had set my .babelrc to the following, which worked, however then it transpiled all my code in webpack which I didn't want, in development mode I want to leave the JavaScript un-transpiled so I can work with it without it being obfuscated.

```
{
   "presets": [ "@babel/preset-env" ]
}
```

Instead I want to run Jest by calling 'npm run test' which then I can specify only that script transpiles the code and then webpack runs without transpiling, I was hoping something like this in my .babelrc file

```
{
    "env": {
      "test": {
        "presets": [ "@babel/preset-env" ]
      }
    }
}
```

Then in my package.json I could set the env to test which then would leave webpack alone.

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "SET env=test&& jest --config jest.config.js"
}
```

With this setup I still get the following message appearing when 'npm run test' runs which shows the babelrc file isn't being hit.

> Jest encountered an unexpected token
>   This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out my test was ok in the .babelrc file

```
{
    "env": {
      "test": {
        "presets": [ "@babel/preset-env" ]
      }
    }
}
```

And the script needed in my package.json was this without setting any node env

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "jest --config jest.config.js"
}
```

It was actually my webpack script that wasn't configured correctly, I needed to add '--env.NODE_ENV=development' at the end

```
webpack --progress --profile --watch --mode development --env.NODE_ENV=development
```

Which could then be checked within my webpack.config file.

```
module.exports = (env) => {
    const isDevelopment = env && env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
    ...
```

then in my rules test for isDevelopment

```
rules: [{
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
    use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: isDevelopment ? {} : { presets: ['@babel/preset-env'] }
    }
},
```